# Finding homonyms in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE Repondant
matricule CHAR(8) NOT NULL,         -- Roll
name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
roll VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Repondant_cc0 PRIMARY KEY (matricule),
CONSTRAINT Repondant_cc1 UNIQUE (courriel),
CONSTRAINT Repondant_matricule CHECK (matricule SIMILAR TO '[0-9]{8}'),
CONSTRAINT Repondant_nom CHECK (LENGTH(nom) > 0),
CONSTRAINT Repondant_prenom CHECK (LENGTH(prenom) > 0),
CONSTRAINT Repondant_courriel CHECK (
  LOWER(courriel) SIMILAR TO
    '[^][()<>:;@\,."[:space:][:cntrl:]]+(\.[^][()<>:;@\,."[:space:][:cntrl:]]+)*\@hotmail.com'
)
);
```

I want to make a request that gives me the name,lastname,email and roll for all the homonyms in the table(same name and same firstname)

I tried

```
(SELECT name,lastname,role,email
FROM Repondant 
Where name = (SELECT name FROM Repondant GROUP BY nom HAVING COUNT(*)>1) AND                
lastname = (SELECT lastname FROM Repondant GROUP BY prenom HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

Problem is, it doesnt give the homonyms, it only gives the persons that have their name and their Lastname at least 1 time in the table, but not alway together.

How should I find the homonyms ?

Comment: Use a self-join, not subqueries.

Comment: "*same name and same firstname*" - isn't a simple `where name = firstname` condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can build a array to check the occurrence of more than a value.
For example this is a variant with a subquery:

```
SELECT * from repondant 
WHERE (name,lastname) in 
(
 SELECT  name,lastname 
 FROM repondant 
 GROUP BY name, lastname 
 HAVING count(array[name,lastname]) > 1
);
```